# Refactoring - Chapter 11, Exercise 3 Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, railstutorial.org

Anyone else working through [Chapter 11 Exercises for Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.2#sec%3afollowing_exercises)?

Chapter 11, Exercise 3 asks:
Refactor Listing 11.31 by adding partials for the code common to the following/followers pages, the Home page, and the user show page.

I'm not seeing anything worth refactoring in the homepage, user show page, or the show_follow page

If anyone came up with something worthwhile for this exercise, would love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find common code to refactor on those pages either.  Perhaps the question is a holdover from previous versions of the tutorial where there wasn't as much refactored code(?).  If you're looking at ways to make the code more compact, I can suggest re-writing your views using Haml, and perhaps taking the static content from the home, contact, about, and help pages, and putting them in Markdown files that you can render.

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor the first block of code from Listing 11.31:

```
<section>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
  <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
  <span><b>Microposts:</b> <%= @user.microposts.count %></span>
</section>
```

because it is essentially the same as the views\shared_user_info.html.erb partial used on the home page (Listing 10.32).  Therefore, you can replace the block of code above with this:

```
<%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
```

Note that you will also need to add `<% @user ||= current_user %>` to the top of the views\shared_user_info.html.erb partial (which is the same as what was necessary to add to the stats partial in Listing 11.20).

Additionally, there is some duplication (though not exact duplication) between the feed_item + feed partials with the user + micropost partials, where depending on which page is being displayed (follow_show, home, or profile) there are one or more elements being listed (name, gravatar, admin delete link, micropost content, micropost time stamp, and micropost delete link).  Those could probably be refactored too to eliminate the feed_item+feed partials and replace them with a combination of the user + micropost partials depending on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked through this exercise and found a solution that works.

First I changed around app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb to use the @user variable if it is set, and the current_user variable otherwise.

app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:

```
<% if @user %>
    <%= link_to gravatar_for(@user, size: 52), @user %>
    <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
    </h1>
    <span>
        <%= link_to "view my profile", @user %>
    </span>
    <span>
        <%= pluralize(@user.microposts.count, "micropost") %>
    </span>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to gravatar_for(current_user, size: 52), current_user %>
    <h1>
        <%= current_user.name %>
    </h1>
    <span>
        <%= link_to "view my profile", current_user %>
    </span>
    <span>
        <%= pluralize(current_user.microposts.count, "micropost") %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

Then I replaced the corresponding information in app/views/users/show_follow.hmtl.erb with the partial _user_info.html.erb

app/views/users/show_follow.hmtl.erb:

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        </section>
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
            <% if @users.any? %>
                <div class="user_avatars">
                    <% @users.each do |user| %>
                        <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <h3><%= @title %></h3>
        <% if @users.any? %>
            <ul class="users">
                <%= render @users %>
            </ul>
            <%= will_paginate %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this answer helps anyone going through M. Hartl's tutorial.